# Elixir ecto: check if postgresql map column has key

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

To use json/jsonb data type ecto suggets [to use fragments](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1).

In my case, I've to use PostgreSQL `?` operator to see if the map has such key, this however it will become something like:

```
where(events, [e], e.type == 1 and not fragment("???", e.qualifiers, "?", "2"))
```

but of course `fragment` reads the PostgreSQL `?` as a placeholder. How can I check if the map has such key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the middle `?` and pass a total of three arguments to `fragment`:

```
fragment("? \\? ?", e.qualifiers, "2")
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> MyApp.Repo.insert! %MyApp.Food{name: "Foo", meta: %{price: 1}}
iex(2)> MyApp.Repo.insert! %MyApp.Food{name: "Foo", meta: %{}}
iex(3)> MyApp.Repo.all from(f in MyApp.Food, where: fragment("? \\? ?", f.meta, "price"))
[debug] SELECT f0."id", f0."name", f0."meta", f0."inserted_at", f0."updated_at" FROM "foods" AS f0 WHERE (f0."meta" ? 'price') [] OK query=8.0ms
[%MyApp.Food{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, id: 1,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-19T03:51:40Z>, meta: %{"price" => 1},
  name: "Foo", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-19T03:51:40Z>}]
iex(4)> MyApp.Repo.all from(f in MyApp.Food, where: fragment("? \\? ?", f.meta, "a"))
[debug] SELECT f0."id", f0."name", f0."meta", f0."inserted_at", f0."updated_at" FROM "foods" AS f0 WHERE (f0."meta" ? 'a') [] OK query=0.8ms
[]
```

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, but I found the method from [this](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/71ed598587cbc2f228c7e96716e5c8319707567a/test/ecto/adapters/postgres_test.exs#L349-L360) test.

Comment: Yeah I've found that too, had to upgrade ecto first to be able to use it, can you just explain me why double `\\`?

Comment: That's because Elixir also uses \ as the escape character, so we need to double escape it to make sure Postgres gets 1 \. You can also use `~S`: `~S|? \? ?| == "? \\? ?"`.